# Can you change folder template and columns for a network shared folder in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, desktop-customization, shared-folders

I know how to customize columns and views on a Win 10 PC for folders on that PC.

I do it for images and videos to show things like date taken or length, etc.  Then I can propagate that to subfolders by changing the template by changing the folder view for all folders of the type.

Problem is that we keep a zillion images on a server that are accessed via a mapped drive and I'd like to be able to set the views for all of the folder and not have to do it for each one.

The options on right-click menu to customize this folder doesn't exist.  Nor under Properties is there a tab for Customize.

So, is there some genius hack to do this or am I missing something?

Comment: If you modify the template for 'General Items', does that modify the view of you're folders on the mapped drive?

Comment: Your question answered it.  Changing the view/template on the PC propagates it to the shares.  Thanks!  It was a real "duh", even if it's not ideal - it would be better to be able to control it at a folder level.